# Optimize site for IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've just lost one hour of my life trying to optimize a site for IE. I failed doing it the normal way and I solved it using tricks like these for some divs:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
div1 for non IE
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
div1 for IE
<![endif]-->
```

Now it is working properly in IE, but is it ok to use these kind of solutions?

Comment: Looks awful. I'm pretty sure that your non-IE code works fine in IE9.

Comment: Welcome to the world of pain that is IE. You'll lose many more hours of your life to it in the future. Yes, sometimes those solutions are okay. Are they the *best* solution? Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it! Not that you can't use these but with the use of CSS / HTML you can normally achieve everything you need to do across browsers - there is always client side scripts to aid also but that is just my recommendation.

Comment: Conditional comments only work in IE and ignored by the modern browsers so using !IE to supply CSS to non-IE browsers has no effect.

Comment: Thanks all for feedback. Rob, yes, it is true for linking to a css file, but if you want to insert a different structured div just for IE you have to use !IE, otherwise IE will display both divs, the regular one and the duplicate for IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I develop a website I always make it clear that different browsers interpreted HTML differently, and that their website may look slightly different in IE than in Chrome, Safari et al, but that the overall appearance, meaning and functions will work. Also I always let them know that I don’t build for IE6 and older, that the website will be visible, but some basic functions and layout principles will not work properly. (I also show them the percentage of users who still use IE6). Does the client explicitely asks for an <IE6 website? Charge extra!

This is the question you should be asking: how important is it to you that your website looks EXACTLY the same in all browsers?

For the rest, optimizing for crossbrowser compatibility can be done with different stylesheets for different browsers. However, I recommend keeping the number of stylesheets as low as possible, and try to use as much as possible CSS-attributes that work for all browsers.

Comment: I doubt that anyone now wants <IE6 optimized websites... IE6 itself is hardly used nowadays;)

Comment: You'd be surprised... but I actually got that question once. The company still ran WinXP and IE6 on their network. But yes, <IE6 is not likely these days. Good riddance!

Comment: companies running on xp/IE6 are still quite common. IE6-marketshare in china is still over 10%. I was referring to the <IE6 part;)

Comment: Yeah, I though so too. I must admit I haven't had anyone asking for a IE4.0 optimized website. I'd probably slap him in the face!

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather bad solution and in my experience in most cases not necessary. You should try to get your markup consistent and not have it change for the different versions (Except  perhaps such weird cases like Table-layout for dropdowns for IE6)
However it's okay, to have several stylesheets for the different IE-versions to deal with the bugs of the different IE-version.

```html
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--...-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="standard-style.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

From IE-8 on, your IE-specific stylesheets should be very vew lines - luckily they are pretty standard-conform from that version on.